# FXO to GSM routing

Tags: voip, telephony, cisco-voip

I am new to VoIP so apologize if this is a dump question

I want to accept a traditional telephone call (FXO) channel and based on the callers extension selection I want to switch the call to set of GSM mobile phones and some extensions inside the office.

Hypothetical scenario will be like this,
- Person A dials our landline number
- Voice interface advice user to dial 111 to contact John and 222 to contact Mary.
- If caller dials 111, call will be connected to John's mobile phone through GSM gateway
- If user dials 222 it should dial the office phone that belongs to Mary
- In case John or Mary are unreachable, call should go to voicemail box

Can anybody give me some instructions to get this done?.

What I am currently thinking is to use D-link DVX-2005F to accept the FXO and switch to GSM using D-link DVG-6008G GSM gateway. Will it be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is rather broad as you don't mention what type of hardware you currently have. What kind of extensions inside the office do you have? VoIP or something more traditional. Do you want to interact with GSM directly or merely switch it out to an FXO channel (in which case it's completely irrelevant that the other end is a GSM phone)?

Comment: Also, recommendation of hardware is specifically not allowed according to the site rules.

Comment: @kll Thanks for the quick response! Actually we have traditional PBX we are planning to introduce new IP PBX devices.

I am thinking to use D-link DVX-2005F to accept the FXO channel and based on the user selection the call will be switched using DVG-6008G GSM gateway.

Hypothetical scenario will be like this
- Person A dial our land line number
- Voice interface advice user to dial 111 to contact john
- Call will be connected to johns mobile phone through GSM gateway
- In case john is unreachable call should be recorded

Does that makes any sense?

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. Interpreting your original question with this in mind, it seems you are looking for instructions how to set this up on a DVX-2005F, correct? I have no experience with that platform and can't give you instructions. I imagine it would be rather straightforward though, have you looked in the manual?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I can say that it is very much possible, and in any PBX. You should check with your PBX provider if the GSM and Analog Gateway are compatible with it or not. If they are compatible the call forwarding part won't be a hassle.